# Custom printstream or printwriter that logs to file and prefixes every line

Tags: java, logging

For my application I would like to have a couple of `PrintStream` or `PrintWriter` instances for every log level, e.g. `INFO`, `DEBUG`, `ERROR` and so on.

The text given to the streams should go:

- To a log file
- To the System out

I would like to prefix ALL lines with a timestamp. (I already have the code done to get the timestamp string)

It should also be possible to give this instance to a exception: `ex.printStackTrace( ApplicationLog.ERROR );`

I have already tried making a class extending `PrintWriter`:

```
package cf.randers.nev.log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import cf.randers.nev.helper.LogHelper;

public  class CustomOutStream extends PrintWriter {

    public String loglevel;
    public boolean isBad;

    public CustomOutStream(String loglevel, File file, boolean isBad) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(file);
        this.loglevel = loglevel;
        this.isBad = isBad;
        System.out.println("Created printstream: " + loglevel + " isBad: " + Boolean.toString(isBad));
    }

    @Override
    public void write(char[] buf, int off, int len) {

        String prefix = LogHelper.getCurrentTime();

        len = len + prefix.length() + this.loglevel.length();

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(len);
        b.append(prefix);
        b.append(this.loglevel);
        b.append(buf);

        if (!this.isBad) {
            System.out.println(b.toString());
        } else {
            System.err.println(b.toString());
        }

        super.write(b.toString().toCharArray(), off, len);
    }

}
```

This unfortuately does not work. I did some debugging on my code and it turns out the method is not even being called unfortunately.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and use a real logging framework instead of reinventing one, like slf4j and logback.

Comment: I did not know about there being some nice frameworks, thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using logback as a framework it it quite easy to set up a logger that does that:

`MyClass.java` (located in `/src/main/java/`)

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MyClass {

    public static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.debug("Enter debug message here.");
    }

}
```

`logback.xml` (located in `/src/main/resources/`)

```
<configuration>

    <timestamp key="bySecond" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd kk-mm-ss" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] [%-5level/%logger{36}] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>logs/log-${bySecond}.log</file>
        <append>false</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] [%-5level/%logger{36}] %msg%n</pattern>
            <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

This configuration prints out everything logged to a timestamped file in `logs` and prefixes all messages nicely.